# Error with Buildozer (Kivy/ KivyMD App). Can you help me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm new here so I don't know anything of this platform.
I've got some problems using Buildozer to create an APK file for my KivyMD app.
Apparently, in my python3 code there are no errors, I can execute it without problems.
But when I run Buildozer using `buildozer android debug` that's my error log:

```
(others compiling rows)
Compiling '/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/.buildozer/android/app/Apod/share/doc/networkx-2.5.1/examples/subclass/plot_antigraph.py'...
Compiling '/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/.buildozer/android/app/Apod/share/doc/networkx-2.5.1/examples/subclass/plot_printgraph.py'...
Listing '/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs'...
Compiling '/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/.buildozer/android/app/main.py'...
Compiling '/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/.buildozer/android/app/sitecustomize.py'...
/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/.buildozer/android/app/Apod/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivymd/uix/picker.py:625: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  op = 1 if operation is "next" else -1
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Error while running "/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 -OO -m compileall -b -f /home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/.buildozer/android/app"
This probably means one of your Python files has a syntax error, see logs above
# Command failed: /home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/Apod/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name apod_searcher --name 'APOD Searcher' --version 0.1 --package org.test.apod_searcher --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/.buildozer/android/app --permission INTERNET --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --presplash /home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/galaxy.png --icon /home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/galaxy.png --orientation portrait --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/Generic:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1683,unix/Generic:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1683'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '1.54.3'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1636'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     PWD = '/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     LOGNAME = 'generic'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE = '/usr/share/code/code'
#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/generic'
#     USERNAME = 'generic'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'it_IT.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Unity'
#     VIRTUAL_ENV = '/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/Apod'
#     GIT_ASKPASS = '/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '820f78c5cb5e4acea69d24cb8bdcd6fc'
#     MANAGERPID = '1462'
#     CHROME_DESKTOP = 'code-url-handler.desktop'
#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'generic'
#     VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE = '/run/user/1000/vscode-git-c1d21643ef.sock'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     PS1 = ('(Apod) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: '
 '\\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ')
#     VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN = '/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:42509'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/generic/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/Apod/bin:/home/generic/.local/bin:/home/generic/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = '51229'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = '/usr/share/applications/code.desktop'
#     TERM_PROGRAM = 'vscode'
#     _ = '/home/generic/Scrivania/Apod_images/Apod/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/generic/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/generic/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/generic/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

It has no sense, can someone help me?

Edit: that's my python code and my KV file:

```
    import certifi      
from kivy.lang import Builder       
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest      
from kivymd.app import MDApp        
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog      
from kivy.uix.image import Image, AsyncImage        

class ApodImages(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.title= "APOD Searcher"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style= "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette= "DeepPurple"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue= "600"
        return Builder.load_file("apod_images.kv")
    
    def DATE(self):
        return str(self.root.ids["enter_date"].text.replace('/', '-')) 

    def make_request(self):
        global PHOTO
        PHOTO= UrlRequest(f"https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&date={(self.DATE())}", on_success= (self.get_photo and self.get_title), on_failure= self.get_error, on_error= self.get_error, ca_file= certifi.where())

    def get_error(self, on_failure, on_error):
        self.root.ids["informative_label"].text= "Spiacente, non è stata trovata alcuna foto."

    def get_photo(self, result, on_success):
        self.root.ids["photo_view"]= AsyncImage(id= "photo_view", source= str(PHOTO.result["url"]), allow_stretch= True, keep_ratio= False)

    def get_title(self, result, on_success):
        self.root.ids["informative_label"].text= PHOTO.result["title"] + "\n\n" + PHOTO.result["explanation"]

    def show_info_app(self):
        return MDDialog(title= "Informazioni Applicazione", text= "APOD Searcher è una semplice app che mostra ogni immagine del progetto APOD sviluppato dalla Nasa.\n\nInserisci nella barra di ricerca il giorno di cui visionare la foto (oppure lascia il campo vuoto per visionare la foto del giorno corrente) e premi il pulsante ""Cerca!""", auto_dismiss= True).open()

    def show_contacts(self):
        return MDDialog(title= "Contatti", text= "Indirizzo e-mail: email_esempio@mail.com\n\nAltri recapiti:", auto_dismiss= True).open()

ApodImages().run()

NavigationLayout:

    ScreenManager:

        Screen:

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                MDToolbar:
                    title: "APOD Searcher"
                    elevation: 10
                    left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: navigation_bar.set_state()]]

                ScrollView:

                    MDGridLayout:
                        rows: 4
                        spacing: 10
                        adaptive_weight: True
                        padding: dp(8), dp(8)
                        spacing: dp(10)

                        AsyncImage:
                            id: photo_view
                            source: "https://www.totaldesign.it/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/colore-nero-owwl6fais9p22dndzj9is937kyonae26xm06jsw808.jpg"
                            allow_stretch: True
                            keep_ratio: False    

                        ScrollView:    
                            
                            MDLabel:
                                id: informative_label
                                text: "Qui appariranno tutte le informazioni sulla foto del giorno cercata."
                                halign: "center"
                                theme_text_color: "Primary"
                                size_hint_x: 1.0
                                size_hint_y: None
                                text_size: self.width, None
                                height: self.texture_size[1]

                        MDTextField:
                            id: enter_date
                            hint_text: "Inserisci la data nel formato ANNO/MESE/GIORNO:"
                            mode: "rectangle"
                            max_text_length: 10
                            color_mode: "primary"
                                    
                        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                            id: request_maker
                            text: "Cerca!"
                            size_hint_x: 0.5
                            size_hint_y: 0.125
                            on_press: app.make_request()
    
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: navigation_bar

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: "8dp"
            spacing: "8dp"

            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: "left"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: avatar.height

                Image:
                    id: avatar
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "56dp", "56dp"
                    source: "/home/generic/Scrivania/galaxy.png"

            MDLabel:
                text: "Astronomy Picture of the Day Searcher"
                font_style: "Subtitle1"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]

            MDLabel:
                text: "Eventuale sito web e/o altro"
                font_style: "Caption"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]

            ScrollView:

                MDList:

                    OneLineAvatarListItem:
                        text: "Info App"
                        on_press: app.show_info_app()

                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "information-outline"

                    OneLineAvatarListItem:
                        text: "Contatti"
                        on_press: app.show_contacts()

                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "contact-mail-outline"
```

Sorry if it's not copied correctly but I'm new and I don't know very well how to do.

Comment: WHat is your python code? It's much harder to debug without it

Comment: I've just added it. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use Kivy so I probably won't be of much help.You did enter the code correctly. :)

Comment: Okay, however thanks.

Comment: `You did enter the code correctly. :)` I meant that you entered the formatting correctly. Sorry that I can't help further. :(

Comment: No problem @TheTechRobo36414519, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the following code to your buildozer .spec file:

```
requirements = kivy==2.0.0, kivymd==0.104.2, sdl2_ttf == 2.0.15
```